# Joomla installation of plug-ins

Tags: joomla1.5

How & where to change fix upload permitions for joomla.

After installation of the plugin or module, i have no rights to edit file/directory.

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either enable the FTP layer and put in your username and password so that Joomla can create new directories with the proper permissions or you need to get a host that runs PHP as a CGI. The latter is preferable as the FTP layer is considered a security risk.

By default, Joomla will try to fix the permissions of files and directories during the install process, but it is not always successful depending on the server configuration. One of these 2 methods should fix your issue with future installs.

Comment: Cannot just modify some file where permitions are set? instead of providing ftp details to page?

Comment: If you just want to fix these permissions then you will need access to the file system so you can at least run a CHMOD on the files and folders. Files should be set to 755 and files to 644. You can usually do this in most FTP programs or in the file manager in your hosting control panel (cPanel, Plesk, etc). Depending on the server setup, you might need to have tech support do it. On some servers, the files and folders are owned by the server instead of the users so you will not be able to change the permissions without having root access.